# Laravel 4 Using HybridAuth: Not Getting Autoloaded in class map

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, hybridauth

After downloading `hybridauth` from `composer`, I always need to manually add the hybridauth's directory in `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, this should be automatic.

Below is my composer.json, can someone point me the problem why hybridauth is not getting written in autoload automatically?

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: did you try running "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: Yes I did even though composer does that automatically after doing an 'update' command

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

using "hybridauth/hybridauth": "dev-master"

also try

artisan dump-autoload command

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the latest update they have changed lot of things and your old code won't work with it.

If you are not getting autoload classes in classmap file then better use older version of **HybridAuth** i.e. 2.9.1

use **"hybridauth/hybridauth": "2.9.1"** instead of "hybridauth/hybridauth": "dev-master"

Classes will be loaded automatically on autoload classmap file.

**This works well on laravel 4 and 5 both.**